# Mapping a JSON response to component model in TypeScript.

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, typescript, angular

I have an Angular 2 app that returns a JSON string. I want to take that JSON string and map its values to a model.

From my understanding, a TypeScript model file is supposed to help in mapping an HTTP Get response to an object - in my case a class classed 'CustomObject'.
Here's my TypeScript model file which I created for TypeScript to recognize:

```
export class CustomObject {
    public Name: string;
}
```

Here's what my JSON string looks like (slightly modified from Chrome dev tools to eliminate unnecessary variables):

```
"{
   "EventType": 3,
   "Description": "Test Description",
   "LocationName": "DefaultLocation",
   "Name": "TestName"
}"
```

I want to take that JSON string and map the 'Name' value ("TestName" to an existing CustomObject's variable I have declared in my home.ts file which is null by default:

```
public activeCustomObject: CustomObject = null;
```

However, after executing the HTTP Get method to retrieve the JSON response (I expect variable 'activeCustomObject' to now its 'Name' field set to 'TestName', calling {{activeCustomObject.Name}} in my HTML file print nothing.  I've done the proper imports and set the providers.

Here's how I'm subscribing:

```
this._customObjectService.getCustomObject()
    .subscribe(res => {
        this.activeCustomObject = res;
    });
```

and this is how I'm calling the GET method:

```
getActiveCustomObject() {
    return this._http.get('/test/customobject')
        .map((response) => {
            console.log(response);
            return response.json;
        });
}
```

Any ideas as to why calling {{activeCustomObject.Name}} print nothing in my HTML? Chrome dev tools show the JSON is returning a proper JSON string with the data I need (mainly name). I plan to use the other values in the JSON string so I can't just make the HTTP GET return the name field - I need to know why the returned JSON string isn't getting mapped to the Custom Object variable.

Comment: Did you resolve your question?

Comment: See accepted answer from Thierry Templier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that it's because your data are loaded asynchronously. I guess that you have an error in your JavaScript console...

You could try to use the Elvis operator this way:

```
{{activeCustomObject?.Name}}
```

I see also another problem. You need to call the `json` method on the response not a property:

```
getActiveCustomObject() {
  return this._http.get('/test/customobject')
    .map((response) => {
        console.log(response);
        return response.json(); // <-----------
    });
}
```

Comment: Didn't even see than json method typo - that fixed it - thanks!